# Bamboo git bisect plugin

Tags: git, bamboo, bisect

Are there any plugins for bamboo that run 'git bisect' automatically on broken tests?
I've tried to search for one but I haven't found any information about such a plugin.
If there isn't, can you suggest me where I can start in order to build one, and which tools should I be using?